# How to prevent system freeze on Wifi activation?

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom

Without myself modifing any configuration setting, my system starts to completely freeze after I activate the wifi network via the network manager or at a `sudo rfkill unblock all`.

I would like to kindly ask for your assistance as I do not understand how to fix it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here's my system information:

```
lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:051b]


uname -r
3.5.0-25-generic


 dmesg | grep b43

***


# Verwendete Kernelversion
uname -a
Linux Lenovo-G570 3.5.0-25-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 25 18:26:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

#Abfrage für PCI und PCMCIA-Karten:
lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet [1969:2062] (rev c1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3979]
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c
--
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:051b]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

# Abfrage für USB-Geräte:
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card reader
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 058f:9254 Alcor Micro Corp. Hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5986:0292 Acer, Inc
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 04d9:1603 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 046d:c03d Logitech, Inc. M-BT96a Pilot Optical Mouse

#Nur bei UMTS/GPRS-Karten bzw. USB-Sticks noch zusätzlich:
usb-devices

#Dazu bitte diese Befehle eingeben und in den Beitrag einfügen:
egrep -v "^$|^#" /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
$egrep -v "^$|^#" /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
$ egrep -v "^$|^#" /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   laptop

# Zuordnung der Schnittstellen:
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

# PCI device 0x14e4:0x4727 (brcmsmac)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="e4:d5:3d:5c:d1:45", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

# PCI device 0x1969:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0 (atl1c)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="dc:0e:a1:68:c1:72", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x14e4:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0 (wl)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="e4:d5:3d:5c:d1:45", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"


#Schließlich geben diese Befehle auch noch Aufschluss über die momentanen Einstellungen:
ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse dc:0e:a1:68:c1:72
      inet Adresse:192.168.178.32  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
      inet6-Adresse: fe80::de0e:a1ff:fe68:c172/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
      RX packets:79998 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:58218 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000
      RX-Bytes:97693373 (97.6 MB)  TX-Bytes:5579450 (5.5 MB)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife
      inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
      inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metrik:1
      RX packets:304 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:304 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0
      RX-Bytes:99657 (99.6 KB)  TX-Bytes:99657 (99.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse e4:d5:3d:5c:d1:45
      BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000
      RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)

$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on

$ route -n
Kernel-IP-Routentabelle
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

#Dazu bitte ein paar Pings
ping -c 4 <routerip>
ping -c 4 www.ubuntuusers.de
ping -c 4 213.95.41.11

#Abfrage der Kanal- und Ländereinstellung:
iwlist chan
eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
      Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
      Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
      Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
      Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
      Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
      Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
      Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
      Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
      Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
      Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
      Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
      Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
      Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

#Manueller Scan der WLAN-Umgebung:
sudo iwlist scan
[sudo] password for hotryce:
eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

#Zustand der Schalter:
rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

#Abfrage der geladenen Kernelmodule
$lsmod

 lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
pci_stub               12623  1
vboxpci                23195  0
vboxnetadp             25671  0
vboxnetflt             23480  0
vboxdrv               287190  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
bnep                   18141  2
rfcomm                 46620  0
bluetooth             209249  10 bnep,rfcomm
parport_pc             32689  0
ppdev                  17074  0
autofs4                36534  1
nfsd                  255927  2
nfs                   301262  0
lockd                  76909  2 nfsd,nfs
fscache                61094  1 nfs
auth_rpcgss            40956  2 nfsd,nfs
nfs_acl                12838  2 nfsd,nfs
sunrpc                229747  6 nfsd,nfs,lockd,auth_rpcgss,nfs_acl
binfmt_misc            17501  1
joydev                 17458  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32049  1
snd_hda_codec_conexant    57802  1
uvcvideo               76750  0
i915                  520615  4
videobuf2_core         32852  1 uvcvideo
videodev              120310  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
usblp                  18141  0
snd_hda_intel          33492  3
videobuf2_vmalloc      12861  1 uvcvideo
drm_kms_helper         49113  1 i915
videobuf2_memops       13405  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
rts5139               356200  0
drm                   288721  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
snd_hda_codec         134213  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel
arc4                   12530  2
coretemp               13401  0
kvm_intel             132760  0
kvm                   414071  1 kvm_intel
ghash_clmulni_intel    13221  0
cryptd                 20404  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
mei                    40691  0
psmouse                95595  0
microcode              22804  0
serio_raw              13216  0
ideapad_laptop         18087  0
snd_hwdep              17699  1 snd_hda_codec
i2c_algo_bit           13414  1 i915
sparse_keymap          13891  1 ideapad_laptop
snd_pcm                96668  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13325  0
snd_rawmidi            30513  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14900  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61555  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29426  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14498  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    78921  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              15048  1 snd
lpc_ich                17062  0
mac_hid                13206  0
snd_page_alloc         18485  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
video                  19391  1 i915
atl1c                  41102  0
brcmsmac              531905  0
mac80211              540032  1 brcmsmac
bcma                   35657  1 brcmsmac
brcmutil               14756  1 brcmsmac
cfg80211              206797  2 brcmsmac,mac80211
cordic                 12575  1 brcmsmac
lp                     17760  0
parport                46346  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
hid_generic            12541  0
usbhid                 46987  0
hid                   100411  2 hid_generic,usbhid


#Erweiterte System- und Fehlermeldungen des Kernels mit einem Filter für die am häufigsten verwendeten Netzwerkkarten und Treiber
dmesg | egrep 'net|eth|sky|sis|via|3c3|3c5|e100|8139|8169|acx|air|ath|atl|ar9|carl|atme|at7|herm|iwl|ipw|rtl8|r81|rt2|rt3|rt6|rt7|tg3|ssb|wl|b43|b44|ori|pri|p5|zd|ndis|wmi|ns8|FW'
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 28 pages/cpu @ffff88023fa00000 s83584 r8192 d22912 u262144
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s83584 r8192 d22912 u262144 alloc=1*2097152
[    0.000000] Calgary: detecting Calgary via BIOS EBDA area
[    0.003368] CPU0: Thermal monitoring handled by SMI
[    0.199661] CPU1: Thermal monitoring handled by SMI
[    0.212866] CPU2: Thermal monitoring handled by SMI
[    0.226055] CPU3: Thermal monitoring handled by SMI
[    0.494297] PCI: Discovered primary peer bus 03 [IRQ]
[    0.494354] PCI: Discovered primary peer bus 04 [IRQ]
[    0.494409] PCI: Discovered primary peer bus 07 [IRQ]
[    0.494464] PCI: Discovered primary peer bus 08 [IRQ]
[    0.494518] PCI: Discovered primary peer bus 09 [IRQ]
[    0.494573] PCI: Discovered primary peer bus 0a [IRQ]
[    0.494626] PCI: Discovered primary peer bus 0b [IRQ]
[    0.494684] PCI: Discovered primary peer bus 0c [IRQ]
[    0.494739] PCI: Discovered primary peer bus 0d [IRQ]
[    0.494793] PCI: Discovered primary peer bus 0e [IRQ]
[    0.601529] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    0.752034] thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
[    0.752036] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ00] (0 C)
[    0.777857] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
[    2.245479] usb 2-1.1.2: Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
[   31.871602] Adding 8191996k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:8191996k
[   33.416556] atl1c 0000:01:00.0: PCI->APIC IRQ transform: INT A -> IRQ 16
[   33.446756] atl1c 0000:01:00.0: version 1.0.1.0-NAPI
[   35.267986] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[   35.276605] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain
[   35.293340] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[   35.437127] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain
[   35.499486] usblp 2-1.1.2:1.0: usblp1: USB Bidirectional printer dev 5 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x1504
[   36.829392] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   45.431999] audit_printk_skb: 6 callbacks suppressed
[   47.818956] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   48.685586] atl1c 0000:01:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[   48.686115] atl1c 0000:01:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Up<100 Mbps Full Duplex>
[   48.693769] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

#Konfiguration des NetworkManagers
$cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state


#Konfiguration des NetworkManagers
cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

### Aktionen:
sudo rfkill unblock all
---> Problem --> Einfireren.


***
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
sudo rfkill unblock all
iwconfig
***

sudo rfkill unblock all
---> problem
```

In gnome-system-log I cannot find a thing. The powermanagement did not change things either. How do I know which is the correct kernel module?

I am really lost.

---

in gnome-system-log I cannot find a thing.

The powermanagement did not change things either.

How do I know which is the correct kernel module?

I am really lost.

Comment: Hi, can you capture the system log (run `gnome-system-log` and try to replicate the issue, then note down what logs that may come up)? Hopefully your system would have time to log events when your problem happens.

Comment: I had a problem with my network driver causing kernel panic on 64-bit systems. Maybe this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/408116/ralink-usb-wifi-completely-locks-up-system/455483#455483) will help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting that the issue here is related with wireless power management.

Please try running this command: `sudo touch /etc/pm/power.d/wireless`. Then try to reproduce your issue.

It'll remove the execution bits of the file `wireless` which is executed whenever the power manager does its work with wireless interfaces.